# win32 Child EDIT is not modified when typing, but can be modified with mouse (copy/paste)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developping an win32 application (not MFC). The main window includes a child dialog, which has a ListView (report mode) control. I am now adding in place editing to sub items of the ListView. For that, I detect double-click (NM_DBLCLK) in the dialog procedure and create a child Edit window this way:

```
    RECT rect;
    ListView_GetSubItemRect(listView,Item,subItem,LVIR_BOUNDS,&rect);
    HWND edit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_RIGHT, L"EDIT", L"", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE /*|ES_WANTRETURN*/,
                    rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, 1.5*(rect.bottom - rect.top),
                    listView, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
                    SetWindowTextW(edit, buffer);
                    Edit_LimitText(edit, 12);
                    Edit_Enable(edit, true);
                    assert(edit != NULL);
                    SetFocus(edit);
                    m_oldEditProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(edit, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)EditProc);
```

EditProc:

```
if(msg == WM_KILLFOCUS) {
    DestroyWindow(wnd);
}
return CallWindowProc(m_oldEditProc, wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

It seem ok, except that the Edit control seems not to handle modification using keyboard. The Edit has focus (blinking caret). I can change selection using keyboard. I can change text using SetWindowText. I can modify content with copy/paste using mouse. But I cannot modify the content of edit with keyboard.

When I use winspy, I see the WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR and WM_KEYUP arriving to the edit window, but no change appears.

I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is this the entirety of your `EditProc()`?

Comment: There will be something before destoying Window (get value et store it to the listview), but now, it is all yes.

Comment: Did you rule out painting artifact? (Edit updated but not properly displayed)

Comment: When editing ListView sub items, I prefer to manipulate the ListView's built-in editor directly. That way, much of the ListView's native behavior can be preserved, you only have to manipulate where the editor appears and which text it handles, letting the ListView handle the rest normally. In `LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT`, use `LVM_GETEDITCONTROL` to get the editor's `HWND`, move it over the subitem, and assign the subitem's text to it, then subclass it to apply the `SWP_NOMOVE` flag in the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message. In `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT`, apply the new text to the subitem and cancel the edit.

Comment: No, I did not remove painting code: I have some state display using an ImageList, but no ownerdraw or paint code.

Comment: I just tried Remy Lebeau's solution. This does not change the problem: The edit window is appearing where it should (over the sub item being modified), but I still cannot modify the value using keyboard. It remains modifiable with a copy using mouse.

Comment: What does your `GetMessage()` loop look like?

Comment: The mainloop is like 

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
   if (! TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelerators, &msg))
   {
    if(!IsDialogMessage(msg.hwnd, &msg)) {
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
   }
    }

Comment: You shouldn't use `msg.hwnd` as the first argument for `TranslateAccelerator` or `IsDialogMessage`. `TranslateAccelerator` needs the handle of your top-level window (or at least, the window that processes `WM_COMMAND` messages), and `IsDialogMessage` needs the handle of an actual dialog.

Comment: Thank you! it works now. It is the IsDialogMessage which made it work (but of course, I keep correction for TranslateAccelerator too).